# Wrapping different versions of static library in dynamic libraries

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, libtool

In my project there is a dependency on a static library (just called `libsomething` from now on) from a 3rd party. Recently, `libsomething` has become available in another version. My task is to provide my software with support for the old and the new version. Only one version of `libsomething` is used at run-time at any given time, but which version this is should be configurable between program runs.

I am using MSVC2005 on WinXP, a secondary objective is to become prepared to switch over to Linux and GCC.

Since both versions of `libsomething` are using the same symbols, linking them both into my executable is out of the question as the symbols of both versions are going to clash all over at link-time.

While I could create two executables (one linking against the old version, the other one using the new version), I cannot implement a decision on which executable to call in the final deployment environment (legacy reasons).

I came up with the idea of creating a dynamic library wrapper for each version of `libsomething` and linking them at run-time depending on some config file. With MSCV, this would mean going down the road of using `LoadLibrary()`, `GetProcAddress()`, etc., while on Linux I would have to use `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`.

I understand that using `libtool` (i.e., `libtldl`) is wrapping this platform-dependency for using shared libraries. Is this an appropriate path to follow? Are there better (or, at least, different) ways? Do alternatives for `libtldl` exist as open-source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been few years now but I'd like to mention another solution for completeness. Instead of manual `dlopen` and `dlsym` you could generate simple stubs for all necessary functions and on first call (or at program startup) decide which library version is needed, load it and resolve the addresses.

You could write a script specifically tailored for your project or use [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so) tool:

```
# This will generate mylib.so.init.c and mylib.so.tramp.S
# which implement stubs. These need to be linked to your
# executable.
$ implib-gen.py mylib.so
```

Implib.so is Linux-only atm but should be easily adaptable to Windows.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I ended up doing back in 2010. So, I guess that makes this the accepted solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you couldn't use two executables due to the decision of which to execute, but couldn't you `exec` back and forth between executables depending on which version is selected at configuration?

Comment: You're right, in this case, this approach does yield a solution. Though I am more interested in doing it via linking. But your idea is clever out-of-the-box-thinking!

Answer (score 2):

On Linux it would be easier for you to link to shared library and use symlinks to correct version - IMO it's much easier than using `dlopen()` + `dlsym()`.

Thus you would create shared libraries for the old and new versions of your library:

`g++ -shared -o libshared.so.1.1 -Wl,-soname=libshared.so.1 -L. -Wl,--whole-archive libstatic.a.old -Wl,-no-whole-archive`

and

`g++ -shared -o libshared.so.1.2 -Wl,-soname=libshared.so.1 -L. -Wl,--whole-archive libstatic.a.new -Wl,-no-whole-archive`

Create the symlinks:

```
ln -s libshared.so.1.1 libshared.so.1
ln -s libshared.so.1 libshared.so
```

Build your application, linking it to the old version of the library. I suppose both versions are binary compatible (ABI not broken), but the new one could have some new symbols.

`g++ -o myapp myapp.cpp -L. -lshared`

Since shared library's `SONAME` is `libshared.so.1` your application will depend on it and will search `libshared.so.1` in paths from `/etc/ld.so.conf` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Before you run your application you may set the `libshared.so.1` symlink to point to `libshared.so.1.2` or `libshared.so.1.1`.

---

Little info about the linker options used here:

> --whole-archive
>              For each archive mentioned on the command line after the --whole-archive option, include every object file in the archive in the
>              link, rather than searching the archive for the required object files.  This is normally used to turn an archive file into a shared
>              library, forcing every object to be included in the resulting shared library.  This option may be used more than once.
>   
>              Two notes when using this option from gcc: First, gcc doesn't know about this option, so you have to use -Wl,-whole-archive.
>              Second, don't forget to use -Wl,-no-whole-archive after your list of archives, because gcc will add its own list of archives to your
>              link and you may not want this flag to affect those as well.
>
> -soname=name
>              When creating an ELF shared object, set the internal DT_SONAME field to the specified name.  When an executable is linked with a
>              shared object which has a DT_SONAME field, then when the executable is run the dynamic linker will attempt to load the shared object
>              specified by the DT_SONAME field rather than the using the file name given to the linker.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Unfortunately,  as you said, this only works with Linux. Therefore it is something worth coming back when I eventually port to Linux, but not applicable before that day.